# Does 'My favorite place, in my bathroom, is hot.' make sense?

Tags: grammar

> My favorite place, in my bathroom, is hot.'

Does this sentence above make sense?

If it is wrong, how can I rephrase it?

Comment: You should include what meaning you intend it to have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sentence makes sense. The prepositional phrase "in my bathroom" as you've punctuated the sentence could be understood to be a reduced form of "which is in my bathroom".   In other words:  I have a favorite place. It is in my bathroom. It is hot there.

But if you were to write "My favorite place in my bathroom is hot." that could mean:  In each of my rooms, I have a favorite place.  In the bathroom, that place is hot.  In the living room, my favorite place is the chair near the window. On the back porch, it is the rocking chair.